# Here Maps Integration into a PWA returning network error

Tags: here-api

I have just started looking at integrating Here Maps into my PWA app.

I have used the code from the Tutorial "Add a Custom Marker to an Interactive Web Map by HERE"

It works if I stick it in a basic index.html page, however when I integrate the code into my existing PWA app I get the following errors:

mapsjs-core.js:407 Refused to connect to 'blob:http://localhost:80mapsjs-core.js:407 Tangram [error]: Scene.load() failed to load blob:http://localhost:8082/5b3657b5-50a5-4092-82e5-a27328817f3b: There was a network error[object ProgressEvent] Error: There was a network error[object ProgressEvent]
at XMLHttpRequest.s.onerror (mapsjs-core.js:407)82/5b3657b5-50a5-4092-82e5-a27328817f3b' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src *". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

followed by

mapsjs-core.js:407 Tangram [error]: Scene.load() failed to load blob:http://localhost:8082/5b3657b5-50a5-4092-82e5-a27328817f3b: There was a network error[object ProgressEvent] Error: There was a network error[object ProgressEvent]
at XMLHttpRequest.s.onerror (mapsjs-core.js:407)

Followed by

mapsjs-core.js:407 Uncaught (in promise) Error: There was a network error[object ProgressEvent]
at XMLHttpRequest.s.onerror (mapsjs-core.js:407)

I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In error message "'blob:http://localhost:80..." - port 80 but other error message contains blob:http://localhost:8082 - port 8082? - here you have some inconsistency.. Do you have two servers - one on port 80 another on port 8082?

Additionally please check the error messaging in Network of DevTools of your Chrome browser.

BTW is working on [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qthjafw8/):

```
//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
    // Replace variable YOUR_API_KEY with your own apikey
    var platform = new H.service.Platform({
        apikey: window.apikey
    });
    var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
    //Step 2: initialize a map - this map is centered over Europe
    var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
        defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
        {
            center: { lat: 50, lng: 5 },
            zoom: 4,
            pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
        }
    );
    // add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());
    //Step 3: make the map interactive
    // MapEvents enables the event system
    // Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
    var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

    // Create the default UI components
    var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

    // Marker code goes here
    var LocationOfMarker = { lat: 19.741755, lng: -155.844437 };

    // optionally - resize a larger PNG image to a specific size
    var pngIcon = new H.map.Icon("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/tourism/eiffel200.png", { size: { w: 56, h: 56 } });

    // Create a marker using the previously instantiated icon:
    var marker = new H.map.Marker(LocationOfMarker, { icon: pngIcon });

    // Add the marker to the map:
    map.addObject(marker);

    // Optionally, 
    //Show the marker in the center of the map
    map.setCenter(LocationOfMarker)

    //Zooming so that the marker can be clearly visible
    map.setZoom(8)
```

It is difficult to understand without analyzing the your code...

It seems that some violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src *" please read on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/connect-src

Comment: Hi, I tracked this down to the content-security-policy in my index.html. I have commented out for now. I will need to do some reading before I enable it again.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `blob:` to child-src csp fixed the issue for me.